# Como usar o "float: left" de maneira correta?

Tags: html, css

Tenho usado bastante o `float: léft;` ultimamente, mas há vezes que ele não funciona como eu espero. Exemplo:
[image: com float e margin estranha]

(imagem 1) Reparem que aparece uma margin que não deveria estar aqui.
[image: sem float o menu fica normal, mas o resto fica todo estranho]
(imagem 2) A margin some, mas como não tem float a outra div fica na linha de baixo.

O objetivo do código é fazer um menu superior parecido com esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele não deveria apenas jogar as divs uma ao lado da outra? Como fixo isso? Por que ele faz isso?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700,600);

*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body{
    background: #ecf0f1;
    color: #2c3e50;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.top-menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #c0392b;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #96271C;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    position: fixed;
}

.top-menu .content{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.burger-menu{
     background: #96271C;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100px;
     float: left;
     position: relative
}

.burger > div{
    width: 21px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.burger{
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 10px;
}

.burger-menu{
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.title-section{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.title-section .title{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.search-section{
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.search-section input, input:focus{
    width: 160px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #96271C;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px #ecf0f1 solid;
    padding:5px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    outline: none;
}



::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #f2f2f2;}
:-moz-placeholder {color: #f2f2f2;}
::-moz-placeholder {color: #f2f2f2;}
:-ms-input-placeholder {color: #f2f2f2;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Menu G1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="top-menu">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="burger-content">
                    <div class="burger-menu">
                            <div class="burger">
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                        </div>menu
                    </div>
                </div>
              
                <div class="title-section">
                    <div class="title">Política
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="search-section">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" name="pesquisa-menu">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu acho que seria importante você [edit] a postagem e deixar bem claro o resultado que quer obter, em vez de querer usar o `float:left` em qualquer ocasião. Pode acontecer de no seu caso o `float:left` não ser adequado pra isso. Ou se quer só aprender sobre o `float`, aí a pergunta já é outra, e as imagens pra cima não são mais relevantes. Lembre-se que quanto mais objetiva a pergunta, maior a chance de uma boa resposta, pois boas respostas dependem da comunidade entender o problema de fato, e não só os desdobramentos que o problema causa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FEIJAO COM ARROZ DO FLOAT:

Pra exemplificar vamos então criar uma div wrap, ela será o elemento pai que servirá de referencia pra conter os elementos flutuantes.

Dentro desse elemento pai teremos duas caixa A e B, vamos usar elas pra brincar com o float. Esse será a nossa estrutura:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
</div>

.wrap{
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.A{
   display:block;
   background:red;
   padding:50px 0;
   width:120px;
}
.B{
   display:block;
   background:blue;
   padding:50px 0;
   width:120px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Dê uma olha no link pra você entender melhor: https://jsfiddle.net/ow6ds5bk/

Primeiramente vamos flutuar as duas caixas pra esquerda, então vamos colocar o float NOS DOIS ELEMENTOS que queremos flutar

```
.A{float:left}
.B{float:left}
```

Se você olhar no nosso código https://jsfiddle.net/ow6ds5bk/3/ verá que flutuou os elementos como o pretendido, porém algo está errado. O elemento pai se desmanchou, e o restante da página continuou sendo flutuado. Vamos corrigir isso.

Vamos criar uma classe clear, ela servirá pra resetar a flutuação após as nossa caixas, assim não afetará o resto da página e tambem vai consertar o nosso elemento pai:

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Agora o nosso html ficará assim:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<span>Float é fácil</span>

.wrap{
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.A{
  display:block;
  background:red;
  padding:50px 0;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
.B{
  display:block;
  background:blue;
  padding:50px 0;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Se você olhar para a nossa pagina verá que alcançamos a estrutura desejada: https://jsfiddle.net/ow6ds5bk/4/

Você precisa ficar atento também para o tamanho dos elementos, se a soma do width de todos os elementos superarem o width do elemento pai, algumas coisas podem ser empurradas pra baixo, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/ow6ds5bk/5/

Toda propriedade que mexe com a dimensão do elemento também deve ser considerada pra conta: margin, padding, border, width, etc.

Agora Vamos ousar mais, queremos um elemento à direita e o outro à esquerda. Não é difícil basta usar a mesma lógica:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<span>Float é fácil</span>

.wrap{
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.A{
  display:block;
  background:red;
  padding:50px 0;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
.B{
  display:block;
  background:blue;
  padding:50px 0;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Mamão com açúcar né? Veja como ficou o nosso exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/ow6ds5bk/7/

Legal, agora vamos colocar os dois elementos pra direita, basta usar a mesma lógica anterior certo? ERRADO: https://jsfiddle.net/ow6ds5bk/8/

Veja que as caixas ficaram invertidas, isso acontece por que a caixa A é o primeiro elemento a ser exibido, então ele será o primeiro flutuado pra direita.

Pra resolver isso vamos criar um elemento que flutuará pra direita, ele vai abrigar as nossas 2 caixas. As caixas flutuarão pra esquerda fazendo o efeito que nós procuramos:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

.wrap{
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
.A{
  display:block;
  background:red;
  padding:50px 0;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
.B{
  display:block;
  background:blue;
  padding:50px 0;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
.right-container{
  float:right;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Veja como ficou agora o nosso exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/ow6ds5bk/6/ coisa linda!

Acho que isso é básico pra trabalhar com float sem ter sustos. Mas usar float pra montar o layout do site não é legal, existem muitas outras alternativas que você pode e deve usar: grids, frameworks html, flex. A menos é claro se você não se preocupa em se desesperar sempre que a sua página é exibida numa resolução diferente.

Apesar de não ser recomendado, é bom saber. Vai que um dia você precisa dar manutenção num site montado com float?

---

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Se você der uma olhada no código, verá que eu fiz uma marcação no código pra definir onde deve ocorrer a limpeza das flutuações. Mas essa é uma técnica muito antiga, antes do CSS2, quanto não tínhamos os seletores `:before` e `:after` .

Podemos utilizar uma técnica mais moderna pra realizar a mesma função:

Basta criar a classe clearfix:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
   content: " ";
   display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
   clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
   *zoom: 1;
}
```

Basta adicionar a classe clear fix no elemento pai referente aos elementos que receberão a flutuação.

```
<div class="wrap clearfix">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
</div>
<span>Float é fácil</span>
```

Assim você terá um código mais limpo. Veja como o nosso exemplo ficou: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezZGOw

Answer (score 2):

A real utilidade do *float* é fazer um bloco flutuar em cima de bloco de texto, como por exemplo aquelas colunas de jornal.

**Ele não serve para fazer layout**, utilizam ele como gambiarra já que não existia um padrão pra fazer esse tipo de coisa, você até consegue fazer layout com *Float* mas é uma dor de cabeça horrivel que só quem já fez e teve que dar manutenção no código sabe.

Dá uma olhada em [Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/), ele resolve parte do problema de fazer layout, tem uns frameworks que implementam ele pra você usar com Sass e Stylus, já tem um bom suporte dos navegadores e é uma coisa linda trabalhar com ele <3

Comment: Realmente, refiz o Layout usando flexbox e é muito mais fácil de mandar! Valeu.

Comment: Brother, embora vc teve o aceite na resposta e 2 positivos, acredito que deveria rever seu conceito sobre float... Ele permite que os elementos flutuem a sua direita ou a esquerda, ou float:none, que nega a flutuação ao seu redor.. Elementos posicionados absolutamente ignoram a propriedade float.

Comment: Um adendo, o flex css não tem suporte a todos os navegadores. Os malditos IE6~9 não suportam o comando e mesmo a versão mais atual do IE ainda apresenta alguns bugs. Versoes mais antigas do navegador padrao do android também não suportam, porém não é um problema pra se alarmar, o suporte do Flex atinge cerca de 90% dos usuários, só será um problema se você precisar dar suporte pros IE antigos

Comment: se liga na dica: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBxGXb4iTQw&feature=youtu.be